# SSL certificates or other files not showing in Docker file structure

Tags: docker, docker-build

I have a Docker build for Gitlab, I created some ssl certificates and other files I need to pull in.  However when I exec into the container bash the files are not visible.

```
gitlab:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:9.1.0-ce.0'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
  links:
    - postgresql:postgresql
    - redis:redis
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      postgresql['enable'] = false
      gitlab_rails['db_username'] = "gitlab"
      gitlab_rails['db_password'] = "gitlab"
      gitlab_rails['db_host'] = "postgresql"
      gitlab_rails['db_port'] = "5432"
      gitlab_rails['db_database'] = "gitlabhq_production"
      gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = 'postgresql'
      gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = 'utf8'
      redis['enable'] = false
      gitlab_rails['redis_host'] = 'redis'
      gitlab_rails['redis_port'] = '6379'
      external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com:30080'
      nginx['ssl_certificate'] = '/etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/gitlab.example.com.crt'
      nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = '/etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/gitlab.example.com.key'
  ports:
    - "30080:30080"
    - "30022:22"
postgresql:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:9.6.2-alpine
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=gitlab
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=gitlab
    - POSTGRES_DB=gitlabhq_production
redis:
  restart: always
  image: redis:3.0.7-alpine
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with more appropriate scenario. It's very abstract now.

Comment: Show your Dockerfile please, that's a start

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Where did you add your certificates? Or is the container supposed to create them for you? I only see the definition for a very long environment variable.

Comment: The certificates (self signed) are on my machine at the path referenced "/etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/gitlab.example.com.crt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On creation of the self signed certificates, I need to exec into my docker container and create them using the docker bash

Answer (score 0):

> The certificates (self signed) are on my machine at the path referenced "/etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/gitlab.example.com.crt"

Your docker-compose.yml did not map any folders from your host into your container. Containers are nothing more than a namespaced process, and one of those namespaces is the filesystem. To map a directory from the host into the container, you can use a simple bind mount syntax:

```
gitlab:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:9.1.0-ce.0'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
  volumes:
    - ./path/to/gitlab.example.com.crt:/etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/gitlab.example.com.crt:ro
  ...
```

Note that this mounts from the host into the container, and the file will be configured as read-only with the `:ro` syntax to prevent processes inside the container from modifying your certificates. If your docker host is inside of a VM (including docker for windows/mac) or on a remote server, you'll need to make sure the files are accessible there (e.g. docker for win/mac has settings to share PC folders into the embedded VM).